# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, json, pandas, machine-learning

I work at this project on jupyter notebook and all the cells run normally except the last which gives me an error. Can you help me to find it?(I added two comment lines where the problem starts)

**here is the code:**

```
import numpy as np
import json
import os
import re
import collections
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import codecs
import pickle
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText
import sys
from __future__ import division
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
from surprise import NormalPredictor
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate
from surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization import SVD
from surprise.model_selection import KFold
from surprise import accuracy
from surprise.prediction_algorithms import KNNBasic
from surprise import accuracy
from threading import Thread
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

from surprise import NormalPredictor
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate
from surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization import SVD
from surprise.model_selection import KFold
from surprise.prediction_algorithms import KNNBasic
from surprise import accuracy
from threading import Thread
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

def normalize_name(name):
    name = name.lower()
    name = re.sub(r"[.,\/#!$%\^\*;:{}=\_`~()@]", ' ', name)
    name = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', name).strip()
    return name

#Load Training Data change path name as per your directory
path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\dataset'
mapping = {}
playlist_prob = OrderedDict()

#Mapping of playlist name to filename
def load_filemapping():
    fp = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\folder\\track_filename.json')
    mpd_mapping = json.load(fp)
    return mpd_mapping

mpd_mapping = load_filemapping()

#Change this as per you files folder location
fp = open('C:\\User\\user\\Desktop\\folder\\album_stats.json')
album_map = json.load(fp)
album_stat = sum(album_map.values())

#Change this as per you files folder location
fp = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\folder\\artist_stats.json')
artist_map = json.load(fp)
artist_stat = sum(artist_map.values())

#Change this as per you files folder location
fp = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\folder\\tracks_stats.json')
track_map = json.load(fp)
track_stat = sum(track_map.values())

print(album_stat,artist_stat,track_stat)

#Get playlist name, track and value
def data_dict():
    for key,value in playlist_prob.items():
        for subkey,subvalue in value.items():
            yield key,subkey,subvalue

#Load Data in surprise format
def load_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dict(),columns=['userID','itemID','rating'])
    reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0,1))
    data = Dataset.load_from_df(df[['userID','itemID','rating']],reader)
    n_tracks = df['itemID']
    yield data,n_tracks

#Training has been performed using Collaborative Filering
#For similarity cosine similarity has been used and similarity between users is calculated

def train(data):
    
    sim_options = { 'name' : 'cosine',
                    'user_based' : True
                  }
    def data_send(data):
        yield data
        
    trainset, testset = train_test_split(data_send(data).next(),test_size=.25)
    
    def train():
        yield trainset
    def test():
        yield testset
    
    algo = KNNBasic(k=40,sim_options=sim_options)
    algo.fit(next(train()))
    prediction = algo.test(next(test()))
    print(accuracy.rmse(prediction,verbose=True))
    return algo

#Predict ratings for empty tracks

def test(playlist_name,tracks,algo,seed_tracks):
    def track_filter():
        for track in tracks:
            if track not in seed_tracks:
                #print(track)
                yield track
    
    def track_predict(tracks_pred):
            yield tracks_pred
        
    def sort_dict(Recommend):
        for (key,value) in sorted(Recommend.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True):
            yield key
        
    print('Filtering Tracks')
    tracks_pred = [track for track in track_filter()]
    Recommend = {}
    print('Predictng')
    for track in next(track_predict(tracks_pred)):
        predict = algo.predict(playlist_name,track)
        Recommend[track] = predict[3]
    print('Sorting List')
    recommend_list = [key for key in sort_dict(Recommend)]
    print('Sending List')
    return recommend_list[0:500]

#Load data with scores
fp = open('C:\\Users\\sotir\\Desktop\\newfolder\\tracks_stats.json')
playlist_prob = json.load(fp)

#Change the directory as per your directories

path1 = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\folder'
challenge_file = 'challenge_set.json'
filename = os.sep.join((path1,challenge_file))
fp = open(filename)
challenge_set = json.load(fp)
playlists = challenge_set['playlists']

import csv
#Load exisiting ratings into the dicitonary
count = 0

test_tracks = {}

for playlist in playlists:
    if 'name' not in playlist.keys() and playlist['num_samples'] == 10:
        count+=1
        print(count,playlist['pid'])
        playlist_prob[playlist['pid']] = {}
        seed_tracks = []
        i = 0
        list_temp = []
        list_temp.insert(0,playlist['pid'])
        for track in playlist['tracks']:
            p1 = artist_map[track['artist_uri']]/artist_stat
            p2 = album_map[track['album_uri']]/album_stat
            p3 = track_map[track['track_uri']]/track_stat
            playlist_prob[playlist['pid']][track['track_uri']] = (p1+p2+p3)/(1+track['pos'])
            seed_tracks.insert(i,track['track_uri'])
        test_tracks[playlist['pid']] = seed_tracks


# until this line jupyter notebooks cells run normal
# when i run the code below I get the error

#Send data for training
print('Loading data for training')
data,n_tracks = next(load_data())
print('Training')
algo = train(data)
```

**Here is the error I get when I run the code:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16948/1757410543.py in <module>
      1 #Send data for training
      2 print('Loading data for training')
----> 3 data,n_tracks = next(load_data())
      4 print('Training')
      5 algo = train(data)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16948/3694601451.py in load_data()
      1 #Load Data in surprise format
      2 def load_data():
----> 3     df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dict(),columns=['userID','itemID','rating'])
      4     reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0,1))
      5     data = Dataset.load_from_df(df[['userID','itemID','rating']],reader)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    682         elif is_list_like(data):
    683             if not isinstance(data, (abc.Sequence, ExtensionArray)):
--> 684                 data = list(data)
    685             if len(data) > 0:
    686                 if is_dataclass(data[0]):

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16948/1562689438.py in data_dict()
      2 def data_dict():
      3     for key,value in playlist_prob.items():
----> 4         for subkey,subvalue in value.items():
      5             yield key,subkey,subvalue

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**Here is a part of a json file that the program reads**

```
{
    "info": {
        "generated_on": "2017-12-03 08:41:42.057563", 
        "slice": "0-999", 
        "version": "v1"
    }, 
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "Throwbacks", 
            "collaborative": "false", 
            "pid": 0, 
            "modified_at": 1493424000, 
            "num_tracks": 52, 
            "num_albums": 47, 
            "num_followers": 1, 
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "pos": 0, 
                    "artist_name": "Missy Elliott", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0UaMYEvWZi0ZqiDOoHU3YI", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:2wIVse2owClT7go1WT98tk", 
                    "track_name": "Lose Control (feat. Ciara & Fat Man Scoop)", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:6vV5UrXcfyQD1wu4Qo2I9K", 
                    "duration_ms": 226863, 
                    "album_name": "The Cookbook"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 1, 
                    "artist_name": "Britney Spears", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:6I9VzXrHxO9rA9A5euc8Ak", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:26dSoYclwsYLMAKD3tpOr4", 
                    "track_name": "Toxic", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:0z7pVBGOD7HCIB7S8eLkLI", 
                    "duration_ms": 198800, 
                    "album_name": "In The Zone"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 2, 
                    "artist_name": "Beyonc\u00e9", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:0WqIKmW4BTrj3eJFmnCKMv", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:6vWDO969PvNqNYHIOW5v0m", 
                    "track_name": "Crazy In Love", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:25hVFAxTlDvXbx2X2QkUkE", 
                    "duration_ms": 235933, 
                    "album_name": "Dangerously In Love (Alben f\u00fcr die Ewigkeit)"
                }, 
                {
                    "pos": 3, 
                    "artist_name": "Justin Timberlake", 
                    "track_uri": "spotify:track:1AWQoqb9bSvzTjaLralEkT", 
                    "artist_uri": "spotify:artist:31TPClRtHm23RisEBtV3X7", 
                    "track_name": "Rock Your Body", 
                    "album_uri": "spotify:album:6QPkyl04rXwTGlGlcYaRoW", 
                    "duration_ms": 267266, 
                    "album_name": "Justified"
                },
```

Comment: It would seem that your `playlist_prob` object is not in the form that you expect.  This should be pretty easy to solve by stepping through the code with your debugger.

Comment: the error is pretty evident IMHO.

Comment: The error is telling you that `value` is an `int` at the time you call the `data_dict()` function on your inputs. Try tracing your inputs and outputs step-by-step to see where the problem is occurring